# url routing in codeigniter like wordpress clean url

Tags: codeigniter, url-routing

How to code or achieve this url like wordpress

for example

```
http://www.example.com/product/view/my-product-sample
```

is there way to have this url ? any tips tutorial example thank you guys :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is already a valid URL without any alteration, calling the controller `product`, method `view` with the argument `my-product-sample`.

However, I think you are looking for [routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html).

Example:

```
$route['product/view/(:any)'] = 'products/view_product/$1';
```

This route is saying: If user requests

```
product/view/(something)
```

give them

```
products/view_product/(something)
```

As usual, see the [user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) for more information.